# why does sam sync --watch fails due to a DockerPushFailedError and ExportFailedError?

Tags: aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I have built a HelloWorld template on python3.9 and packaged as a Docker Image, using AWS SAM CLI.

Every SAM CLI command runs well except for `sam sync --watch --stack-name hello-world` which results in the following error:

```
samcli.commands.package.exceptions.ExportFailedError: Unable to upload artifact helloworldfunction:python3.9-v2 referenced by ImageUri parameter of HelloWorldFunction resource.
```

I have no problems uploading the image into ECR when deploying or even when running `sam sync` with the `--code` flag. I have tried using the `--resource-id` flag, to no avail.

I have no idea what is going on here... help!

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

COPY app.py requirements.txt ./

RUN python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t .

# Command can be overwritten by providing a different command in the template directly.
CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

Here is my build `template.yaml`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: 'python3.9

  Sample SAM Template for hello-world

  '
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      Architectures:
      - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
      ImageUri: helloworldfunction:python3.9-v2
    Metadata:
      DockerContext: /Users/nelson/Applications/hello-world/hello_world
      DockerTag: python3.9-v2
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
      SamResourceId: HelloWorldFunction
Outputs:
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function
    Value:
      Fn::Sub: https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: Hello World Lambda Function ARN
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt:
      - HelloWorldFunction
      - Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt:
      - HelloWorldFunctionRole
      - Arn
```

Here is the traceback when I run debugging (`sam sync --watch --stack-name hello-world --debug`):

```
2022-07-11 23:46:40,776 | Building image for HelloWorldFunction function
2022-07-11 23:46:40,780 | Setting DockerBuildArgs: {} for HelloWorldFunction function
Step 1/4 : FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
 ---> a0bdfefcccf7
Step 2/4 : COPY app.py requirements.txt ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8437c09ef028
Step 3/4 : RUN python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 38afa314fe71
Step 4/4 : CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> af4fc1a40809
Successfully built af4fc1a40809
Successfully tagged helloworldfunction:python3.9-v2

2022-07-11 23:46:40,878 | Async execution completed
2022-07-11 23:46:40,879 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource HelloWorldFunction, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2022-07-11 23:46:40,880 | Auto creating dependency layer for each function resource into a nested stack
2022-07-11 23:46:40,880 | 2 resources found in the stack 
2022-07-11 23:46:40,880 | Found Serverless function with name='HelloWorldFunction' and ImageUri='None'
2022-07-11 23:46:40,880 | --base-dir is not presented, adjusting uri /Users/nelson/Applications/hello-world/hello_world relative to /Users/nelson/Applications/hello-world/template.yaml
2022-07-11 23:46:40,880 | --base-dir is not presented, adjusting uri . relative to /Users/nelson/Applications/hello-world/template.yaml
2022-07-11 23:46:40,880 | No function has been added for auto dependency layer creation

Build Succeeded
2022-07-11 23:46:40,888 | No Parameters detected in the template
2022-07-11 23:46:40,900 | Sam customer defined id is more priority than other IDs. Customer defined id for resource HelloWorldFunction is HelloWorldFunction
2022-07-11 23:46:40,900 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource ServerlessRestApi, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2022-07-11 23:46:40,900 | 0 stacks found in the template
2022-07-11 23:46:40,950 | Sam customer defined id is more priority than other IDs. Customer defined id for resource HelloWorldFunction is HelloWorldFunction
2022-07-11 23:46:40,950 | Sam customer defined id is more priority than other IDs. Customer defined id for resource HelloWorldFunction is HelloWorldFunction
2022-07-11 23:46:41,417 | Unable to export
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 943, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.35/images/sha256:af4fc1a40809d6386a8fc05e05bcc6bfcaa9c0fc353028dddf6b372210e8c676/tag?tag=helloworldfunction-af4fc1a40809-python3.9-v2&force=0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/package/ecr_uploader.py", line 88, in upload
    docker_img.tag(repository=repository, tag=_tag)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/models/images.py", line 122, in tag
    return self.client.api.tag(self.id, repository, tag=tag, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 547, in tag
    self._raise_for_status(res)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("invalid reference format")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/package/packageable_resources.py", line 273, in export
    self.do_export(resource_id, resource_dict, parent_dir)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/package/packageable_resources.py", line 286, in do_export
    uploaded_url = upload_local_image_artifacts(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/package/utils.py", line 118, in upload_local_image_artifacts
    return uploader.upload(image_path, resource_id)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/package/ecr_uploader.py", line 101, in upload
    raise DockerPushFailedError(msg=str(ex)) from ex
samcli.commands.package.exceptions.DockerPushFailedError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("invalid reference format")
2022-07-11 23:46:41,419 | Failed to sync infra. Code sync is paused until template/stack is fixed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 943, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.35/images/sha256:af4fc1a40809d6386a8fc05e05bcc6bfcaa9c0fc353028dddf6b372210e8c676/tag?tag=helloworldfunction-af4fc1a40809-python3.9-v2&force=0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/package/ecr_uploader.py", line 88, in upload
    docker_img.tag(repository=repository, tag=_tag)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/models/images.py", line 122, in tag
    return self.client.api.tag(self.id, repository, tag=tag, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 547, in tag
    self._raise_for_status(res)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("invalid reference format")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/package/packageable_resources.py", line 273, in export
    self.do_export(resource_id, resource_dict, parent_dir)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/package/packageable_resources.py", line 286, in do_export
    uploaded_url = upload_local_image_artifacts(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/package/utils.py", line 118, in upload_local_image_artifacts
    return uploader.upload(image_path, resource_id)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/package/ecr_uploader.py", line 101, in upload
    raise DockerPushFailedError(msg=str(ex)) from ex
samcli.commands.package.exceptions.DockerPushFailedError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("invalid reference format")

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/sync/watch_manager.py", line 190, in _execute_infra_sync
    self._execute_infra_context()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/sync/watch_manager.py", line 143, in _execute_infra_context
    self._package_context.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/package/package_context.py", line 138, in run
    exported_str = self._export(self.template_file, self.use_json)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/package/package_context.py", line 160, in _export
    exported_template = template.export()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/package/artifact_exporter.py", line 293, in export
    exporter.export(full_path, resource_dict, self.template_dir)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/package/packageable_resources.py", line 277, in export
    raise exceptions.ExportFailedError(
samcli.commands.package.exceptions.ExportFailedError: Unable to upload artifact helloworldfunction:python3.9-v2 referenced by ImageUri parameter of HelloWorldFunction resource.
500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("invalid reference format")
2022-07-11 23:46:41,424 | No Parameters detected in the template
2022-07-11 23:46:41,436 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource HelloWorldFunction, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2022-07-11 23:46:41,436 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource ServerlessRestApi, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2022-07-11 23:46:41,436 | 0 stacks found in the template


^C2022-07-11 23:46:48,171 | Shutting down sync watch...
2022-07-11 23:46:48,172 | Sync watch stopped.
```

Why am I getting this error solely on this command?!

Answer (score 2):

There are, at least, two solutions.

You can run the same command with the `--image-repository` or `--image-repositories` flag. For example:

```
sam sync --watch --stack-name hello-world --image-repository <account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<repository-name>
```

Alternatively, you can edit your project-level configuration file (.toml) and save the the image repository(ies) URI(s) as a parameter(s) under the `sync` command. I added the following lines to my file called `samconfig.toml`:

```
[default.sync.parameters]
image_repositories = ["HelloWorldFunction=<account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<repository-name>"]
```

[You can learn more about the AWS SAM CLI configuration file here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-config.html#deploy-guided)

In order to find your image repository(ies) URI(s), you must have deployed your application. Otherwise, you will have not pushed your image to ECR, in the first place.

Afterwards,

1. you may look in your configuration file (.toml) under the `[default.deploy.parameters]`
2. or, if you have the permissions, you may describe the stack and search for the repository URI, using the following command:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --stack-name <stack-name>
```

---

Honestly, though I fixed the error, I do not understand why these changes are necessary. Why are the deployment parameters not copied under `sync` in the `.toml` file upon each deployment? Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: I've got the same issue.  This feels hacky af... wish someone from Amazon was listening here.

Comment: Very helpful info. Thank you @zephel